# How to see a list of a user's github pull request reviews?

Tags: github

I'd like to see a summary of the pull requests where I contributed review comments.

Currently I review the list of all pull requests with a URL such as

```
https://github.com/user/project/pulls?q=is%3Apr
```

Because multiple people review, I can't rely on setting myself as the Assignee of the pull request.

Adding my username to the search terms doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following URL:

```
https://github.com/search?q=commenter%3Adefunkt+repo%3Aajaxorg%2Face&type=pr
```

This will find all pull requests (`type=pr`) on GitHub from the `@ajaxorg/ace` repository where user `defunkt` made a comment.

The [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/) can tell you how to do more if you need it.